# Error using codistributed/subsasgn (line 131) Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, spmd, matlabpool

I'm running my code in parallel, my local profile has two cores. this code is Forward algorithm in hidden markov model. my code is here:

```
function [ eln_alpha ] = forward_algo( Obs,P,Pi_0 ,Q )
  parpool('local',2);
n = length(Pi_0);
T = length(Obs);
eln_alpha = zeros(n,T,'distributed');
parfor i1=1:n
    eln_alpha(i1,1) = elnproduct( eln(Pi_0(i1)) , eln(Q(i1,1)) );
end;
fi = T / numlabs;
 P ;
spmd       % =================>>>    line 45
    if labindex == 1
        labSend(P, 2);
        labSend(Q, 2);
    end
    if labindex == 2
        P = labReceive(1);
        Q = labReceive(1);
    end
    for t = ((labindex-1)*fi)+1:(labindex * fi)
        if t==1
            t=t+1;
        end
        for j=1:n
            logalpha = NaN;
            for i1=1:n
                logalpha = elnsum(logalpha , elnproduct( eln_alpha(i1,t-1) ,eln(P(i1,j)) ) );
            end;
            eln_alpha(j,t) = elnproduct(logalpha , eln( Q(j,t) ));
        end;
    end
end
end
```

The result of `elnsum` and `elnproduct` and `eln` is just one value in `double` type.

and I get this error :

> Error using forward_algo>(spmd) (line 45)
>       Error detected on workers 1 2.
>       Error in forward_algo(line 45)
>       spmd
>
> ```
> Caused by:
> Error using codistributed/subsasgn (line 131)
> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
> Error using codistributed/subsasgn (line 131)
> Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts
> ```

As it appears I'm not trying to assign multiple values into a single left hand location to cause `Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts` error.
anybody can help?

thank you

Comment: which line exactly do you get the error at? We have no way to know which lines are 45 and 131..

Comment: @nirvana-msu thank you for reminding me, line 45 is the line of `spmd`. but the 131th line of subsasgn  is not my code, it is matlab's predifined functions. the problem is that because it is running in parallel I cant debug it and I dont know which line cause the error.

Comment: What if you replace `spmd` with a normal `for` loop (with required adjustments)? Can you reproduce the error then? If so, you'd be able to debug and see exactly what went wrong

Comment: no it will run correctly, I first wrote the sequential code then I am changing it to parallel @nirvana-msu

Comment: Then I suggest you to add logging commands at multiple places in your code, until you find the line that fails. Your main problem seems to be in the missing stack trace, so alternatively, wrap the code inside `spmd` into `try`/`catch`, then display the stack trace manually using `getReport`, before you leave the worker.

Comment: @nirvana-msu unfortunately `getReport` function doesn't work in `spmd` block